# Is there a sharper bound than exponential for $\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{m!(k+n-m)!}{(k+n)!}\frac{s^k}{k!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying find a bound for an expression and I am getting something not quite as convenient as I hoped. Going through my calculations again I think that the only place I use a non sharp bound is when I wrote
$$\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{\binom{k+n}{m}}\frac{s^k}{k!}\le e^s,$$
for $m\le n$, which of course comes from the fact that $\binom{k+n}{m}\ge1$. So, is there a sharper bound for that series or I am stuck with it?

Comment: That depends, what you are after. If you fix $m,n$ and think of $s$ being large, then can be more precise. The binomial coefficient is roughly $k^{m}$ times a constant for large $k...$

Comment: Well, I think it will be enough to have a result for big $s$ but since I am summing also in $n$ and $m$ I need an accurate form of the constant. Is there any book where I can find approximations? I don't really have a background in combinatorics.

Comment: If you want to keep everything precise, then the best way to estimate binomial coefficient is to apply Stirling formula. The cheap way to improve your bound is to put smth like $\frac{m!e^s}{ P(s)}$ where $P(s)$ is certain polynomial.

Comment: The ratio between consecutive terms in the sum is $\frac{s (k-m+n)}{k (k+n)}$; setting this equal to $1$ and solving for $k$ yields an annoying expression that isn't that far away from $s$ - perhaps bounded between $s-m$ and $s$. The single term in the sum corresponding to that value of $k$ is of course a lower bound for the sum, not an upper bound, but I suspect that the lower bound isn't too far from the truth. (The same game applied to the usual $\sum s^k/k!$ only misses the mark by about $\sqrt s$.) So perhaps the sum is close to $e^s/\binom{s+n}m$...?

Comment: @leshik I found the Stirling formula not so useful as I am after a closed form bound and the Stirling formula gives me something that I don't know what to do with. And your second suggestion seems problematic since I then want to sum over $m$ and a factorial will really destroy everything.

Comment: @GregMartin I am completely lost with your comment. I have no idea how to get a bound from the ratio? Could you explain what happens with the exponential?

Comment: my suggestion was basically the same to what Greg Martin mentioned: the Binomial coefficient essentially behaves in the same way as the expression I gave.

Comment: @leshik I'm lost. I cannot see the point. Can you explain it a bit more?